# Multiplication in Fortran giving different results with ifort and gfortran

Tags: floating-point, fortran, gfortran, intel-fortran

I have a program that is compiled either on Linux with gfortran-9, either on Windows with ifort. The windows compilation is kind of a black box on which I don't have much access.

Anyway, at some point both code have to do the same multiplication but the result is different at the 13th decimal.

Here the test code I wrote to test this multiplication on my Linux machine:

```
      implicit none
      double precision:: a,b,c,d
 200  format(F35.20)
      b=20.17865682672815452747d0
      c=3.75000000000000000000d0
      d=32.17399999999999948841d0
      a=b*c*d
      write(*,200)a
      end program
```

On Linux with gfortran I have 2434.60539278681835639873 value. On Windows with ifort the same multiplication is done and gives 2434.60539278681881114608 . Both are compiled with -O2 option.

I can't think of a reason why it differs. Is it because the double precision can't be more precise and that I should move to the `real(16)`?

Thanks for your insights.

Comment: Be aware that the result of this program can be pre-computed during the compilation stage and that happens differently. BTW, ifort on Linux gives the same answer as gfortran.

Comment: " result is different at the 13th decimal." --> The difference is in the 17th _significant_ digit (start the count from the 2 in 2434).  At about 15,16,17 decimal digits, code is reaching the limit of the FP 53 bit binary precession.

Comment: The Linux `2434.605392786818 356....` result is consistent with a 64-bit `double`.  The  windows result  `2434.605392786818 811...` is closer to the better product of  `2434.605392786818 625...` yet does not look like a 64-bit `double`.   There remains a question of  the correctness of the multiplication  vs. the conversion to decimal text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 3 different ways that the multiplication can be ordered. Gfortran and ifort happen to choose different orders. Using brackets you can see what is going on:

```
ian@eris:~/work/stack$ cat mult.f90
implicit none
      double precision:: a,b,c,d
 200  format(F35.20)
      b=20.17865682672815452747d0
      c=3.75000000000000000000d0
      d=32.17399999999999948841d0
      a=(b*c)*d
      write(*,200)a
      b=20.17865682672815452747d0
      c=3.75000000000000000000d0
      d=32.17399999999999948841d0
      a=b*(c*d)
      write(*,200)a
      b=20.17865682672815452747d0
      c=3.75000000000000000000d0
      d=32.17399999999999948841d0
      a=c*(b*d)
      write(*,200)a
      end program
ian@eris:~/work/stack$ gfortran --version
GNU Fortran (Ubuntu 7.4.0-1ubuntu1~18.04.1) 7.4.0
Copyright (C) 2017 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
This is free software; see the source for copying conditions.  There is NO
warranty; not even for MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.

ian@eris:~/work/stack$ gfortran -O2 mult.f90
ian@eris:~/work/stack$ ./a.out
          2434.60539278681835639873
          2434.60539278681881114608
          2434.60539278681881114608
```

Both answers are perfectly correct - you are just seeing one of the effects of floating point maths.

Comment: Thanks you very much for this insight! that's explain a lot. I was not looking for which one is correct but to understand why it is giving different results.